# How to space existsing array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

i have these arrays

```
lvls_y = np.array([40, 45, 48, 40, 49, 42], dtype=float)
line_y = np.array([44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44])
```

i want to space the **UNSORTED** array **lvls_y** so i can find the intersection points between lvls_y and line_y

NOTE:

note that array is not sorted , so i can't use linspace

is there any way to space an existing array ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. What is the expected result? Show us how you would do it by hand?

Comment: i want the intersection points  see [here](https://i.ibb.co/9NpJYFG/Screen-Shot-2019-10-21-at-6-29-09-AM.png) to understand

Comment: Try to solve it for each pair of 2-element-long subarrays. I mean first check if lvls_y[0:2] and line_y[0:2] intersect. Next check if lvls[2:4] and line_y[2:4] intersect and so on. I guess this operation can be vectorized

Comment: i thought about that but is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution <3

i np.linspace each pair then return the final list , im not sure if there is an other solution , but thats works for me

```
def space_array(a, spacing):
    two_elements_space = (spacing / len(a)) + 2 * len(a)
    final_array = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if(i + 1 <= len(a) - 1):
            final_array.extend(np.linspace(a[i], a[i + 1], two_elements_space, endpoint=False))
        else:
            final_array.extend([a[i]])
    return np.array(final_array)
```